# Why am I not able to run this curl command?

Tags: command-line, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I tried to create a custom model for my IBM Watson Visual Recognition API, by following the IBM's docs. I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: The command is correct so its most likely a File System issue - either your files are not in the same directory, or are your missing the proper rights. Also, you should not share your api key and you should leave out the "{" "}".

Comment: @briadeus Yeah. I didn't know that I should not share my api key with anyone. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues here

1. The auto unzipping feature (enabled) on your MacBook. Because of this, the Zip files are unzipped and the .zip files are moved to **Trash** folder. Just move the .zip files from Trash to the folder you are pointing to on the Terminal and run the command. It works!!
2. There's no need of curly braces in your API key, here's the curl command that worked for me (highlighted example APIKEY value)

   curl -X POST -u "apikey:**4nsDxUBNqlcL1bU_aAJl9lxxxxxxxx**" -F "beagle_positive_examples=@beagle.zip" -F "goldenretriever_positive_examples=@golden-retriever.zip" -F "husky_positive_examples=@husky.zip" -F "negative_examples=@cats.zip" -F "name=dogs" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classifiers?version=2018-03-19"